# Changing a UILabel text from another class

Tags: class, text, uilabel

I have created a UILabel in a UIViewController and a function to change that label, they are initialised as follows in the .h file:

```
@interface StoreDetailsController : UIViewController {
UILabel *storeNameLabel;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *storeNameLabel;

- (IBAction)LabelTheStore:(int)storeNumber;
```

then in the .m file:

```
@synthesize storeNameLabel;

...

-(void)LabelTheStore:(int)storeNumber
{
    NSLog(@"CHECK NUMBER: %d", storeNumber);
    storeNameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    storeNameLabel.text = @"TEST";
}
```

An int variable is passed to the function which will then be used. The log shows the correct number based on what I pass through it, so I know the function is being called correctly, but the label never updates when I call the function from another class. If I call NSLog on the storeNameLabel.text is shows up being (null).

The storeNameLabel is linked correctly in interface builder and the program builds OK.
Update:

The method to load the StoreDetailsController:

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    StoreDetailsController *storeDetailsController = [StoreDetailsController alloc];
    storeDetailsController = [storeDetailsController initWithNibName:@"StoreDetailsController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

    NSInteger row = indexPath.row;
    [storeDetailsController LabelTheStore:row];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:storeDetailsController animated:YES];
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: It is highly unusual to be allocating and initializing a storeDetailsController each time a table row is selected; this is likely the problem.  The normal approach is 1) you have one view for storeDetails and one controller for that view, 2) when you select a row you change the content of that one view.  In your tableViewController you need to access the storeDetailsController.  That access is normally setup in Xcode Interface Builder - but there are loads of ways to do it.  The more modern way would be with a segue from the cell in the table view to the storeDetailsController.

Comment: A less modern way it to put 'IBOutlet storeDetailsController storeDetailsController' in the header file for you tableViewController and then to link it in Xcode IB.  Then you don't allocate it.  Your didSelectRowAtIndexPath becomes: { [self.storeDetailsController LabelTheStore: indexPath.row]; /* push, deselect */ }

Comment: @GoZoner I have completely rewritten my application to utilise the storyboard features. I am now at the same stage but I am having trouble using a segue to display the storeDetails view. Do you have an tutorials or advice you could give me?

Answer (score 0):

In your LabelTheStore method you are allocating a UILabel each time; that is not voting to work.  In your UI you have a view which is being controlled by StoreDetailsController.  The view should have a UILabel in it that is linked to the IBOutlet for storeNameLabel in the controller.  You linked it; it is already allocated so you don't need to allocate it again.

The content of LabelTheStore should just be:

```
self.storeNameLabel.text = @"TEST";
```

If that method is being called and you are still not seeing the label change then ensure that the IBOutlet from StoreDetailsController is connected to the UILabel.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I have amended the code as you stated but it's still not updating the label. I tried adding an NSLog to display the label.text after updating it but it's still coming up as (null). .

Comment: I'm thinking there's a problem with how I've initialised the StoreDetailsController. I have a Tab Bar Application, one of the tabs loads a subclass of a UITableViewController with a list of store names. When in row is selected it that creates an instance of StoreDetailsController, initialises it with the .xib file, then uses pushViewController to push that view into view. The LabelTheStore function I am trying to call is also called in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath function within the UiTableViewController class. Thanks again for your help

Comment: I've just added a button to the StoreDetailsController view and linked it to the LabelTheStore function and the label updates correctly if I press it once the view has loaded. If I then go back to the TableView and select a row again it displays the label without updating it, but pressing the button again updates it? So it must be with how I am setting up the view. Any ideas?